# How to replace opening and closing curly braces by square brackets and remove labels on a json array in Java script ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json array,

```
var arr=[
{prjId: 230482046, prj: "#1 Cochran", Type: "Invoice", Date: "07-12-2019", Num: "T5917"},
{prjId: 230482182, prj: "#1 Cochran", Type: "Invoice", Date: "07-12-2019", Num: "T5919"},
{prjId: 210640692, prj: "#1 Cochran", Type: "Invoice", Date: "07-15-2019", Num: "T4256"},
{prjId: 210641051, prj: "#1 Cochran", Type: "Invoice", Date: "07-15-2019", Num: "T4298"},
{prjId: 210641170, prj: "#1 Cochran", Type: "Invoice", Date: "07-15-2019", Num: "T4300"}
];
```

I want to display this json array items in pdf sheet as table contents so I used pdf make third party library but the problem is, according to their code I  need above json array as following format

```
var arr=[
[prjId,prj,Type,Date,Num],
[ 230482046, "#1 Cochran", "Invoice", "07-12-2019","T5917"],
[ 230482182, "#1 Cochran", "Invoice", "07-12-2019","T5919"],
[ 210640692, "#1 Cochran", "Invoice", "07-15-2019","T4256"],
[ 210641051, "#1 Cochran", "Invoice", "07-15-2019","T4298"],
[ 210641170, "#1 Cochran", "Invoice", "07-15-2019","T4300"]
];
```

How will I achieve this?

Comment: `var result = [[ 'prjId', 'prj','Type','Date','Num' ]].concat( arr.map( ({ prjId,prj,Type,Date,Num }) => [prjId,prj,Type,Date,Num] );`

Comment: @Paulpro  Fantastic Answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get property names of an object, and [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get property values.

Try this:

```js
var arr=[
{prjId: 230482046, prj: "#1 Cochran", Type: "Invoice", Date: "07-12-2019", Num: "T5917"},
{prjId: 230482182, prj: "#1 Cochran", Type: "Invoice", Date: "07-12-2019", Num: "T5919"},
{prjId: 210640692, prj: "#1 Cochran", Type: "Invoice", Date: "07-15-2019", Num: "T4256"},
{prjId: 210641051, prj: "#1 Cochran", Type: "Invoice", Date: "07-15-2019", Num: "T4298"},
{prjId: 210641170, prj: "#1 Cochran", Type: "Invoice", Date: "07-15-2019", Num: "T4300"}
];

var result = [];

result.push(Object.keys(arr[0]));

for (var item of arr) {
  result.push(Object.values(item));
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @Paulpro - Thanks for pointing it out. `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` also orders results consistent with `Object.keys()`. `Reflect.ownKeys()` uses `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` to compute the values. So, even these won't guarantee order.

Comment: @Paulpro - Using `for` loop with index, or `forEach()`, or `for...of ` loop would guarantee the order. I will edit my answer to make that distinction.

Comment: MDN Documentation of [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) says that it gives results with ordering consistent with `Object.keys()`. So what is the point of using it then?

Comment: There are conflicting answers about order guaranteeing but the consensus seems to that from ES2015, insertion order is preserved in case of non-integer keys, but with integer keys it still varies between platforms.

Comment: I wouldn't split hairs anymore on this, but thanks for bringing it up @Paulpro. I learned a lot about the topic. Also, when I mentioned `for` loop with numeric index, `forEach()`, and `for...of` loop guaranteeing order, I mentioned it in the context of iterating over arrays, not over property names of object. This wasn't clear on my part. Thanks!